# Unity - Android | Отображение элементов поверх других окон

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, 2d

Как дать разрешение приложению на показ элементов поверх окон? Так же как например вывести на экран картинку, текст, линию или кнопку (Всё что угодно)?

Как пример: Программы для показа FPS в играх, Программы для записи на Android (Где на экране появляется круг и при нажатии на него открывается меню, где можно остановить запись и прочие)

Допустим, если нажать на кнопку - Появиться текст на экране. Если свернуть приложение и открыть какое-нибудь другое - Текст останется и будет виден поверх всех приложений/программ.

Comment: Так андройд или PC? Для каждой платформы и операционной системы свое решениею

Comment: @aepot Для Android и PC, Лучше для Android (В первую очередь)

Comment: В таком случае отредактируйте вопрос, сконцентрируйтесь на одной проблеме, а не на нескольких. Универсального решения все равно нет.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980478/how-to-create-a-floating-window-like-clipboard-pro-app

Comment: @Style-7 Мне на Unity, C# надо, а там Java

Comment: принцип один и тот-же и код почти такой же

Comment: Ну если на андроиде то там надо вкл пункт в настройках поверх всех приложений "android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" Я не спец по unity но попробуйте совместить https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-RequestingPermissions.html